# `flex` appearing differently on mobile device to desktop

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

### Issue

I have a site that works and previews fine on desktop devices responsively, however on mobile it appears incorrectly.

It includes a full-page `flex` container with two elements that share the horizontal space.

On tablet and mobile, the `flex` container is set to `column` so that it displays vertically instead, however **when visiting the site on my mobile device the elements are stacked upon each other**.

---

### Code

*`index.php`*

```
<div class="flex">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header Title</h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Subheading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End header -->

    <!-- Timeline -->
    <div class="timeline">
        <h2>Timeline</h2>
        <ul class="timeline-both-side">
            <li>Element</li>
            <li>Element</li>
            <li>Element</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End timeline -->

</div>
```

*`style.css` - desktop:*

```
div.flex {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
}

div.hero {
    height: 100vh;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
}

div.timeline {
    flex: 0 0 640px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 66px); /* to account for footer */
}

div.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,calc(-50% - 66px)); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,calc(-50% - 66px)); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,calc(-50% - 66px));
}
```

*`style.css` - tablet:*

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    div.flex {
        height: auto;
        flex-direction: column; /* vertical! */
    }

    div.timeline {
        height: auto;
        margin: auto;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        flex: 1 100%;
    }

    div.hero {
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        flex: 1 100%;
    }

    .timeline-both-side {
        width: auto;
    }

    div.header {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        -ms-transform: none; /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: none; /* Safari */
        transform: none;
    }
}
```

*`style.css` - mobile:*

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.hero {
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

---

### Images

View in Google Chrome for Desktop (previewing as expected):

[image]

View in Google Chrome for Desktop in "Device Mode" for iPhone 6 (previewing as expected):

[image]

View on iPhone 6 (Portrait) - no main header visible:

[image]

View on iPhone 6 (Landscape) - elements stacked on top of one another:

[image]

---

### Question

Why are the `flex` child elements stacking on top of one another *only* when viewing on mobile devices, while previewing fine responsively in my desktop browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the `flex` container's `display` attribute to `block`, then doing the same for its children:

```
.flex, .hero, .timeline { display: block; }
```

Comment: So you solved flexbox problem by *not using flexbox*?

Comment: @Paulie_D I couldn't find a solution using `flexbox`, so I decided to go with `display:block` for mobile/tablet layouts. It works, so it's a solution - nobody else replied with a better one!

Comment: @Paulie_D It's not closed and it's been 3 hours...? If you have a solution I'm listening! :)